# Locate error by ASP.NET stack trace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I receive ASP.NET errors in Event Log.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
```

It contains following info:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at 0.5.0(Exception )
   at 0.5.7(Object , EventArgs )
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.OnError(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.some_page_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I assume that the exception occurred in a custom error handler. I don't know what are the 0.5.7 and 0.5.0. How to find the error position?

Debug mode is turned off. Pages are precompiled. ASP.NET 4.0. IIS 7 integrated mode.

Similar error:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetNextEvent(RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostEvent, Int32 eventIndex)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

These errors were generated constantly until IIS restart.

**UPDATE:**

I enabled debug mode - no additional info in event log.

Enabled failed requests tracing - the log does not contain any useful info.

```
ModuleName
ManagedPipelineHandler 

Notification
128 

HttpStatus
500 

HttpReason
Internal Server Error 

HttpSubStatus
0 

ErrorCode
0 

ConfigExceptionInfo


Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 

ErrorCode
The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

Comment: It might be obsfucated code, which means it jumbles up the names, and you won't be able to find out without having access to the original code.

Comment: It'll be fine if I can determine an assembly name at least. I temporarily enabled debug mode and waiting for the error.